# How to show hide the element that was selected with closest and find method in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, show-hide, closest

I have form with check box and text area. If checkbox is check I want to show textarea if not hide. Here is example of what I have:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dc-checkbox', setCheckboxVal);

function setCheckboxVal() {
  var fldCheckbox = $(this);
  var fldComment = $(this).closest('div').find('.dc-comment');
  console.log(fldComment);

  if (fldCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
    fldCheckbox.val(1);
    fldComment.show();

  } else {
    fldCheckbox.val(0);
    fldComment.hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.dc-comment {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="myfrm" method="post">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="dc_status1" id="dc_status1" class="dc-checkbox"> Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group dc-comment">
    <label for="comment1" class="pull-left">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="dc_comment1" id="dc_comment1"></textarea> </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="dc_status2" id="dc_status2" class="dc-checkbox" value="1"> Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group dc-comment">
    <label for="comment2" class="pull-left">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="dc_comment2" id="dc_comment2"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox4"><input type="checkbox" name="dc_status4" id="dc_status4" class="dc-checkbox"> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group dc-comment">
    <label for="comment4" class="pull-left">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="dc_comment4" id="dc_comment4"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see if I check the checkbox comment textarea is still not showing. I'm not sure if `.closest()` and `.find()` are methods that support show/hide in this case. Please let me know if you know the way to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).closest('div')` finds the first parent div, in this case the one with class `checkbox` - `.find(..)` then looks in that div's *children*.  As the `div class=checkbox` div doesn't have `div class=dc-comment` as its child, it doesn't find it.

`.dc-comment` is a sibling (same level / same parent) as `.checkbox`.

Change to `.next()` or `.nextAll(".dc-comment").first()`

Don't use `.next(".dc-comment")` unless you know what it does as it may break (gets the next only if it matches, not the next that does match).

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dc-checkbox', setCheckboxVal);

function setCheckboxVal() {
  var fldCheckbox = $(this);
  var fldComment = $(this).closest('div').nextAll('.dc-comment').first();
  //console.log(fldComment);

  if (fldCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
    fldCheckbox.val(1);
    fldComment.show();
  } else {
    fldCheckbox.val(0);
    fldComment.hide();
  }
}
```

```css
.dc-comment {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form id="myfrm" method="post">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="dc_status1" id="dc_status1" class="dc-checkbox"> Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group dc-comment">
    <label for="comment1" class="pull-left">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="dc_comment1" id="dc_comment1"></textarea> </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" name="dc_status2" id="dc_status2" class="dc-checkbox" value="1"> Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group dc-comment">
    <label for="comment2" class="pull-left">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="dc_comment2" id="dc_comment2"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox4"><input type="checkbox" name="dc_status4" id="dc_status4" class="dc-checkbox"> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group dc-comment">
    <label for="comment4" class="pull-left">Comment:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="dc_comment4" id="dc_comment4"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is showing all comment fields when only one check box is checked. I need only to show textarea under the check box that is checked. Hope this make sense.

Comment: So what `nextAll().first()` is ding different than `.next()`? i'm trying to understand your solution. Thank you!

Comment: `.next()` gets the next sibling, whatever it is.  `.next(".cls")` gets the next one only if it's `class=cls` otherwise gets nothing.  `.nextAll(".cls")` finds all the following siblings that match cls, then limit it to the first one with `.first()`.  This way, if you put another div between `checkbox` and `dc-comment`, `.next()` will get the one in the middle, `.next(".dc-comment")` would give nothing and `.nextAll(".dc-comment").first()` will get the correct one, skipping non-dc-comment divs on the way.  In your case where they are directly next to each other `.next()` will suffice.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks for taking time to explain your solution.